# Photoshop automatically add numbers suffixes _02, _03 to my slices filenames - how to get rid of them?

Tags: graphics, adobe-photoshop

SO they look like slice_02.jpg slice_03.jpg

Any idea?

Comment: What kind of names would you rather have it use?

Comment: Did you name your slices with custom names in slice options window?

Answer (score 0):

You can name each slice with a custom name in the Slice window.

Highlight the slice with the slice selection tool, then look for the Slice details in the Slice window.  In there you can rename the slice.

Another good trick is to first make each slice on an individual layer, then convert layers to slices - it names the slices after the layers then.